# Android App Highscore comparisson with facebook friends

Tags: android, facebook

Im working on a pretty simple android game. Its all about getting a high score.

Now that I am almost done with the game and everything is working fine, I would like to implement a highscore list, where people can login into their facebook accounts and see the highscore of friends who also play the game. Like in Draw with friends.

What would be the steps I have to go to achieve this?
Do I need an extra server for this? Is there a tutorial how to do this, or can anybody help please?

Thanks in advance